# Question about interview questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

Would a question about the best answer to a standard interview question be on topic here?

Answer (score 7):

I would say no to specific, task related questions meant to demonstrate *competance* like;

- How do you do X in excel?
- How do you design a program for maximum concurrency?
- Your truck has started to hydroplane, what do you do?

Questions like these are specific to certain jobs and require domain expertise. I think the only "interview questions" that would be on topic would be related to general workplace matters, for instance:

- What is an interviewer looking for when they ask where I see myself in 5 years?
- [How am I supposed to answer "What do you consider your greatest weakness?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3793/42)
- How thoroughly should I explain why I want to work for Company X?

I'm also not a fan of the "Which floor do you drop an egg from" or "How many basketballs will fit in this room" questions. They're more of a gray area than the the above question sets. I'd lean towards not allowing them, myself. If the question is just "answer this specific question with a specific answer" I don't think that's really useful; what's more useful is "What is the interviewer hoping to learn from my answer to this?"

Basically my criteria would be that answers should teach you how to *respond*, not just an exact answer to regurgitate. There aren't right answers for these kinds of interview questions, but answers which show how X applicant is appropriate/inappropriate either for Company Y or Job Z

Comment: 5 Years is exactly the one I had in mind :o)